# Prevent decimal place being entered into input field on mobile

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, google-chrome

I have this javascript code, which, on desktop browsers works well to ensure the user can only enter characters 1 to 9.

However when testing in Chrome on Android, the keypad presented includes dash and period characters which the field accepts. How can I prevent this?

```
    function isNumberKey(evt) {
        var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
        if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
```

UPDATE:

This is how I am using the function in HTML:

```
  <input type="number" class="form-control" 
         onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" />
```

I have another function to prevent being able to copy and paste non numeric chars into the code.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#number').bind("cut copy paste drag drop", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        });     
    });
```

And if all else fails, there's server-side validation.

I really want to stop decimal places being possible on the front end. Remember the character range I specified restricts this fine on a qwerty keyboard - however on android (and probably others) the number key pad allows entering `.` and `-`

Comment: If all you want are numbers, why not explicitly check for the range of 48 - 57?  Not sure why the 31 check is in there

Comment: Also can you show us what event binding(s) you are using this method in?

Comment: @Taplar Could it be to allow for backspace? I've updated my answer to give more detail

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible solution:

```html
<script>
function onlyNumbers(num){
   if ( /[^0-9]+/.test(num.value) ){
      num.value = num.value.replace(/[^0-9]*/g,"")
   }
}
</script>
<input type="text" onkeyup="onlyNumbers(this)">
```

Comment: Thanks, I will check it later

Answer (score 0):

Try using the HTML attributes min and max to set the range of numbers and type=number to allow for only numbers.

`Quantity (between 1 and 5):
<input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="5">`

Comment: That would allow them to put 1.1, 1.1111, 4.9876, etc. - also the input type of `number` does not help with my problem. I am already using it. As you can see, the extra javascript is required to cancel key presses of non numeric characters.

Comment: Ah yep, I misunderstood the question!